How to pass state from one page to another in flutter using BloC
I am new to Flutter and the BloC pattern. I am trying to create a simple counter application that has a Tab layout, in which pressing increment and decrement buttons will update the counter accordingly which will be displayed on tab 2.
I currently have the following:
Main.dart:
import 'package:budgetapplication/global_observer.dart';
import 'package:budgetapplication/sumpage.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:budgetapplication/homepage.dart';
import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';

void main() {
  Bloc.observer = const GlobalApplicationObserver();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  static const appTitle = 'Tab Controller Demo with BloC pattern';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: appTitle,
      home: MyHomePage(title: appTitle),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
            bottom: const TabBar(
          tabs: [
            Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.dark_mode_rounded)),
            Tab(
              icon: Icon(Icons.access_alarm),
            )
          ],
        )),
        body: const TabBarView(children: [
          HomepageTab(),
          Sumpage(),
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Sumpage.dart:
import 'package:budgetapplication/counter_cubit.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';

class Sumpage extends StatelessWidget {
  const Sumpage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: BlocBuilder<CounterCubit, int>(
          builder: (context, state) {
            return Text('$state');
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

GlobalObserver.dart:
class GlobalApplicationObserver extends BlocObserver {
  /// {@macro counter_observer}
  const GlobalApplicationObserver();

  @override
  void onChange(BlocBase<dynamic> bloc, Change<dynamic> change) {
    super.onChange(bloc, change);
    print('THIS IS COMING FROM THE GlobalApplicationObserver!');
    print('${bloc.runtimeType} $change');
  }
}

CounterCubit.dart
class CounterCubit extends Cubit<int> {

  CounterCubit() : super(0);

  /// Add 1 to the current state.
  void increment() => emit(state + 1);

  /// Subtract 1 from the current state.
  void decrement() => emit(state - 1);
}

I am getting the following exception when attempting to run the application:
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following ProviderNotFoundException was thrown building KeyedSubtree-[GlobalKey#7958a]:
Error: Could not find the correct Provider<StateStreamable<Object?>> above this
BlocBuilder<StateStreamable<Object?>, Object?> Widget

I have tried to use the suggestion listed in the exception but for some reason i can't compile when i use builder: (context, child) {...} in my Homepage widget. It does the error is stemming from my Homepage widget when trying to build the child.
I am using
  flutter_bloc: ^8.1.6
  bloc: ^8.1.4

Any help?
EDIT:
I have overcome the error by placing the BlocProvider in the build method in the MyApp class. But what i don't understand is that why was it not working where i had initially placed it?

currently you are not providing CounterCubit instance, you can use on MaterialApp level or if you like to use on specific route, use BlocProvider


But what i don't understand is that why was it not working where i had initially placed it?

Where exactly did you place the BlocProvider before?

You can wrap the MaterialApp with BlocProvider
  return BlocProvider(
      create: (context) => CounterCubit(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: appTitle,

Now it the cubit can be access through the routes.
